# Need to have image from Gallery to show up in IMageView at ALL TIME. Whenever the app starts

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera, android-gallery

I am somewhat frustrated trying to get this to work. Can someone please help me with this. I am new to this and all i want is to get an image from Gallery/Image_capture to show on an ImageView at ALL TIME. I have been back and forth with so many ppl and have got diff answer.

This is the Activity that has a ImageView called editpic. Once user clicks on it,it opens a Dialog asking to choose from Gallery or Camera.

```
public int GET_CAM_IMG=2;
public int GET_GAL_IMG=1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile);
    profile();

private void profile() {
editpic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.editpic);




button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v){

           CharSequence[] names = { "From Gallery", "From Camera" };
          new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Select an option for updating your Profile Picture")
                 .setItems(names, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pos) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pos == 0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
             android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
             startActivityForResult(i, GET_GAL_IMG);
              } else {
               Intent i = new Intent(
                   android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
               startActivityForResult(i, GET_CAM_IMG);
                                }

                            }
                        })
                 .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                                    }
                                }).create().show();
        }});
```

ONCE USER CLICKS IT GOES THROUGH CASE AND SWITCH

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    switch (requestCode) {

    case 2://Camera
        if (resultCode == -1) {
            String encodedImageString = null;
            Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
            String selectedImagepath = getPath(selectedImage);
            editpic.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            Bitmap bmp_image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
     Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
             selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
     String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
     cursor.close();



     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     if (bmp_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos)) {
         byte[] image = baos.toByteArray();
         encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(image,
                 Base64.DEFAULT);
     } else {
         System.out.println("Compreesion returned false");
         Log.d("Compress", "Compreesion returned false");
     }





        break;
    case 3://Selecting from Gallery
        if (resultCode == -1) {
            String encodedImageString = null;
            Bitmap bmp_image = null;
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            bmp_image = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");




            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if (bmp_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos)) {
                byte[] image = baos.toByteArray();
                encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(image,
                        Base64.DEFAULT);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Compression returned false");
                Log.d("Compress", "Compression returned false");
            }

        }
        break;
    }
}
```

TRIED CREATING A METHOD SO I CAN GET THE IMAGE PATH AND THEN USE THAT BUT COULDN'T GET IT TO WORK

```
SharedPreferences userprofile = getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userprofile.edit();
            editor.putString("Imagepath",selectedImagepath);
            editor.commit();
```

AFTER TAKING THE PIC, images comes on Imageview but disappears. I want it to be there as this is a profile pic. It is suppose to be something the contact pic in phonebook.